# Como bloquear que el foco de un control avance al siguiente control en wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación en wpf y una validación sencilla, lo que quiero es que cuando el control no satisfaga la validación no se quite el foco del control por mas que el usuario haga click en otro control. Hice obligar que no salga del control hasta que introduzca unos valores correctos.

Esto en Windows Forms se logra atraves del evento validating que utiliza la clase CancelEventArgs y con la instrucción e.Cancel=true; pues se bloquea que el foco avance al siguiente control.

El problemas es que los controles de WPF no tiene el evento Validating para usar esa clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leyendo tu comentario a otra respuesta veo que estas usando el evento `LostFocus`del `TextBox`. Efectivamente, tratar de establecer el foco en un elemento dentro de su propio `LostFocus` provoca una excepción de `StackOverFlow`, probablemente porque se mete en un bucle infinito de perder el foco y volver a recuperarlo. Esto típicamente se resuelve creando un delegado y usando [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void Txt_Nombre_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = (sender as TextBox);
    if (!noEsVálido)
    {
        var restoreFocus = (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate { text.Focus(); };
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(restoreFocus);
    }
}
```

Yo de todas maneras no te recomendaría usar ese sistema. En mi opinión a nivel de usuario no es muy cómodo, y es mas lógico validar todos los datos al confirmar el formulario, pero es una opinión personal.

Comment: muchas grasias por tu respuesta el motivo de aplicar esta forma de validacion es que me encuentro a dias de tener que terminar mi proyecto se que la validacion que estoy aplicando no es muy optima pero no he encontrado mucho material que me ayude con validaciones en WPF de todas maneras grasias por tu respuesta e interes. bendiciones

Comment: Grasias Muchas Grasias me ayudo tu solucion y grasias por tu tiempo bye

Answer (score 0):

Algo que se me ocurre es captar el evento Lost focus, y regresar el foco si no se cumple la validación.

Comment: si lo intente pero me pero me bota error

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: una pregunta talvez el error esta porque lo estoy ejecutando en el evento lostfocus en que evento deberia ejecutar que el foco no salga del control

Comment: capturo el Txt_Nombre_LostFocus() y adentro establesco Txt_Nombre.Focus(); le hice breakpoint y me di cuenta de que se cicla y me bota error dice "No se Controlo StakerOverFlowException"etc

Comment: A ver, intenta con el evento KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler del textbox, tiene una propiedad Handled que (creo) si la pones en true, no pierde el foco.

Comment: grasias bro por tu comentario pero ya lo resolvi saludos